# Cyclomatic Complexity in openCover and Visual Studio

Tags: opencover

Metrics show different values ​​cyclomatic complexity . Which estimation algorithm uses openCover and built-in analyzer for VisualStudio.

Comment: OT: I am not sure why the down/close votes but if people can't be bothered to at least explain why then they shouldn't press the button IMO.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCover's cyclomatic complexity number comes from the IL (which is what you get after compilation) not the source code which is probably what Visual Studio is using. OpenCover only uses the compiled binaries for instrumentation hence it will run against any .NET assembly regardless of language as long as the PDB is available.